# How to delete a moodle course section from database

Tags: mysql, moodle

I have the following situation. I have a moodle course with Moodle theme New Learning, and course format based on tiles format plugin. If I add a new tile(topic) to the course and I try to delete it nothing happens.

I hide it with css but I want to delete it.

If I connect to database and delete it from mdl_course_sections after checking the section ID and course ID it breaks all the platform.

How can I delete it safely from the database?

I hide it with css but I want to delete it.

If I connect to database and delete it from mdl_course_sections after checking the section ID and course ID it breaks all the platform.

Comment: "nothing happens" - if you are facing any bug with Moodle itself, please use their issue tracker

Comment: Is there any other table in database that includes the section?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: If its not deleting via the front end then I'm guessing there is a bug - try setting the debug level to developer to see if there is an error message, then copy and paste the message in the question above - https://docs.moodle.org/401/en/Debugging#Debug_messages